Вопрос по яндекс картам, векторный графический объект
Не знаю как еще назвать заголовок, может быть векторный графический объект на яндекс карте.
При нажатии на яндекс карте, выбирается "cадовое товарищество Северный" и его красные границы (тонкая линия) на карте. При использовании сочетании клавиш Ctrl + SHIFT + I открывается инструмент разработчика, в нем ищем "data-feature-id", тут сразу покажет какие то координаты:
<path data-feature-id="307db82e-ddde-4d10-9bad-bcb376f00998" d="M129.3385365770664,7.907141776755452 L140.05731346621178,-32.80068480223417 L148.58573159924708,-51.33519031479955 L191.69385604350828,-120.81939050555229 L252.9306944438722,-195.80648103822023 L371.62949764332734,49.545376885682344 L312.8626382665243,92.79101483244449 L318.87447399809025,87.036247654818 L286.11229942156933,46.75258550886065 L235.08160075522028,72.39539592619985 L233.82330955355428,87.71327962912619 L197.56588164321147,112.42484792042524 L130.08419062173925,18.65527504775673 Z" stroke-opacity="0.7" stroke="#d54747"></path>

Предполагаю, что как раз это то мне и нужно, но вот что за координаты  "M129.3385365770664,7.907141776755452 L140.05731346621178,-32.80068480223417". где используются, как называются, можно ли перевести в систему координат WGS84 или можно использовать (для отрисовки на карте) эти координаты.

Оказывается это SVG код. сайт для отрисовки нашел. https://editsvgcode.com/

Согласно пользовательскому соглашению Яндекс Карт:

любое копирование Данных… запрещается, за исключением случаев, прямо
предусмотренных функциональными возможностями сервиса.

Попытка извлечь интересующие вас данные со страниц сервиса это условие нарушает.
Сейчас сервис не делится векторными объектами. Все данные, что допустимо получать от наших геопродуктов, описаны в справке соответствующих API.

Спасибо, я знаю про это, но руководству... ну Вы поняли)). Приму Ваш ответ. а так, что такое SVG показывается в хорошем видео. для начала будет достаточно...
